# Obter número do atributo id numa tag <img> dentro de ciclo while

Tags: php, javascript, html

O problema é o seguinte: eu  tenho um ciclo while em `PHP` e preciso de ir buscar o valor de um atributo `id` dentro de uma tag `img`. Esse valor é dinâmico porque lhe atribui uma variável `PHP`.

```
$getLastFour = mysqli_query($dbc,"Select * From products Order By id_product DESC LIMIT 4") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getLastFour)){
        $idProd = $row["id_product"];
        $name = $row["name_Product"];
        $price = $row["prod_price"];
        $description = $row["prod_description"];
        $idImage = $row["img_id"];

?>
                            <div class="b-wrapper"><h2 class="b-animate b-from-left b-delay03 ">
                                <img src="images/link-ico.png" class="img-responsive" id="<?php echo $idImage ?>"  alt="" onclick="showId();"/></h2>
                            </div>
<?php
        }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showId () {
                var id = document.getElementById('<?php echo $idImage ?>');
                var nodeList = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
                    nodeList[i] = id[i];
                }
                alert(nodeList[i]);
            }
        </script>
```

O problema é como o `id`receberá valores diferentes, ao ir buscar o valor com `javascript` este retorna "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta passar o elemento como parametro pro método:

```js
function showId(el) {
  alert(el.id);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/iphone-bk-icon-64.png" id="um" onclick="showId(this);">


<img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/1971286922493102958.png" id="dois" onclick="showId(this);">


<img src="http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/16965988981513619283.png" id="tres" onclick="showId(this);">
```

Comment: Obrigado! Estava a complicar o que era fácil!